# How to handle db objects with Swagger?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, persistence

Hey fellow programmers,

I've got a question regarding Swagger.io, I'm looking for the best way to pass objects.

Recently I made a REST-api with Swagger and deployed it with Restlet studio. It's all fine, code works. I can easily show single objects.

Now the thing is i want to return all the Employees from the database. So my swagger definitions are Employee with some variables and then Employees as an Array list of employees. [See Swagger here.](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/380917/hrsystem/1.0.0)

However employees in the code generated by Restlet, contains a List< String >.

```
public class Employees {
/** Default serial version ID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private java.util.List<java.lang.String> list;



public java.util.List<java.lang.String> getList() {
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<java.lang.String>();
    }
    return list;
}

public void setList(java.util.List<java.lang.String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

What I'm doing now is like:

1. Make JSONArray of all db rows
2. Make every array object as JSONObject
3. Make JSONObject String
4. Add string to List< String > of the employees list...

And this feels so inconsistent, can anyone help how to do this properly? 
Or have an example code of his/hers own project?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I don't know much about Swagger and the code generation, but what I would do, is pretty much define the endpoint and convert the Objects to/from json using a JSON Serializer/Deserializer like Jackson.

Comment: Well maybe it goes wrong at my swagger side, i return an object with an array, but maybe i should return an array with objects.. looking at it now.

Comment: An Array or a List ;-), but an object with a list should work as well.

Comment: The thing is Swagger gives a JSON Object or Array, but uses a String in Java code. I think it is logic to make it as a string in code, because Swagger generates the models as well. But i don't know how to properly use this throughout the code

Comment: Like said, I don't know much about Swagger Code Generation, but I think that It does not really make sense to use JSONObject / JSONArray throughout your code. Use something like GSON or Jackson for the conversion of a String (JSONObject) to your real objects.